# How to add external service data to currently signed in user in Meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor

I was playing with the loginWithExternalService methods under Accounts and I was sad to find that while you could create new users with one of these services or log in those who already had credentials, there was no way of allowing currently logged in users to augment their methods of authentication so that they could log in with any of the services they have authenticated through. Is there a way of dumping information like a user's FB profile or a user's Twitter url into their existing, currently logged in account? I tried customizing accounts-base but this.userId returns null within it so I cannot do updates to the currently logged in user there.

Comment: The answer I gave on this question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18576532/194957

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should probably be a better API for this, but at the moment (Meteor 0.5.2) the following server code will create a user associated with an Facebook ID.

```
var newlyCreatedUserId = Accounts.updateOrCreateUserFromExternalService(
  'facebook',
  {id: FACEBOOK_ID},
  {additionalFieldOnUserDocumented: 'foo'}).id
```

If you dig into the implementation of `Accounts.updateOrCreateUserFromExternalService` you can see how to add these fields to an existing user.

Comment: I am looking at the code right now and it doesn't seem like that method can find people who are currently logged in. It uses the returned info from Facebook to find someone:                      var selector = {};
    selector["services." + serviceName + ".id"] = serviceData.id;
    var user = Meteor.users.findOne(selector);