# How to add External Service logins to an already existing account in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

Having created a profile page for my app, I would like to display a list of social services that the user is on. It struck me that the easiest way would be to use Meteor's built in accounts system for this.

Is there a good way to add external services to an existing account?

Also, will the user then be able to log in with either (e.g.) Facebook **and** his password from my app?

Another question that naturally follows: Is there a good way to add an application specific password to an account that was created with an external service?

Comment: I'm learning, did you manage to do it like it's explained in the answer, or your own way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Meteor Accounts package to link multiple services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358007/using-meteor-accounts-package-to-link-multiple-services)

Answer (score 7):

Here's an alternate method.  In this solution, I'm overriding a core function and adding some custom behavior.  My goal is to associate the service data with the currently logged in user, then allow the core function to do its thing like normal.

```
orig_updateOrCreateUserFromExternalService = Accounts.updateOrCreateUserFromExternalService;
Accounts.updateOrCreateUserFromExternalService = function(serviceName, serviceData, options) {
  var loggedInUser = Meteor.user();
  if(loggedInUser && typeof(loggedInUser.services[serviceName]) === "undefined") {
    var setAttr = {};
    setAttr["services." + serviceName] = serviceData;
    Meteor.users.update(loggedInUser._id, {$set: setAttr});
  }
  return orig_updateOrCreateUserFromExternalService.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Pros:

- Avoids creation of unnecessary accounts
- Code is short and easy to understand
- Code is easy to remove if this functionality is added to Meteor core

Cons:

- Requires the user to be logged in. If a user logs in with twitter initially, logs out, and then logs in with facebook, then two seperate accounts will be created.
- Users who share a computer may get their accounts merged unintentionally.
- Relies on knowledge of how updateOrCreateUserFromExternalService works.  This isn't terrible - because it's part of Meteor's public api it probably won't change drastically (not often anyway). But it's still risky.

Comment: This looks like the best answer I can find, but I can't get it to work. I add it to run on the server, include accounts-password and accounts-facebook. Then I log in with a password, call Meteor.loginWithFacebook() and it adds a service object that's empty to Meteor().user(). It also logs an error in the server console that says: Exception while invoking method 'login' Error: Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls. User this.userId in publish functions.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I add credentials to existing user account: [.../meteor-how-to-login-with-github-account.html](http://ondrej-kvasnovsky.blogspot.com/2013/07/meteor-how-to-login-with-github-account.html)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a user account can be associated with multiple services and have a password-based login at the same time. In the [Meteor docs](https://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_users), you can see the structure of such a user account:

```
{
  _id: "bbca5d6a-2156-41c4-89da-0329e8c99a4f",  // Meteor.userId()
  username: "cool_kid_13", // unique name
  emails: [
    // each email address can only belong to one user.
    { address: "cool@example.com", verified: true },
    { address: "another@different.com", verified: false }
  ],
  createdAt: 1349761684042,
  profile: {
    // The profile is writable by the user by default.
    name: "Joe Schmoe"
  },
  services: {
    facebook: {
      id: "709050", // facebook id
      accessToken: "AAACCgdX7G2...AbV9AZDZD"
    },
    resume: {
      loginTokens: [
        { token: "97e8c205-c7e4-47c9-9bea-8e2ccc0694cd",
          when: 1349761684048 }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

For adding a username/password login to an existing account, you can use `Accounts.sendResetPasswordEmail` on the server side. This also ensures the change happens authenticated and authorized.

Of course you can also just update the user record on the server side with a new password yourself, but this might create a security hole in your app. I would also advise against implementing your own crypto protocol for this if possible, as [it is hard](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/2210).

If you want to add other services than email, you could for example

1. call a server method that saves a random, long token in the current user's MongoDB document and returns it to the client.
2. re-login the user with another service using `Accounts.loginWith[OtherService]`. This logs the user out and in again, using a new account on the other service.
3. call a second server method with the returned token from the first method as parameter. This second method searches for the user account with the given token and merges its data into the current (new) account.

Comment: Yes, but how do you add multiple services?

Comment: Starting to. Definitely seems like a terrible hack and that it should be built into Meteor though. I'll give it a shot tomorrow and accept your answer if I get any joy

Comment: I've awarded you the bounty, but only because you're the only answerer. I don't think this is a satisfactory answer though really, so I haven't accepted it

Comment: Thank you! I also think this should be included in Meteor itself, even if Meteor's own implementation might look similar in the end. Have you been able to implement it this way or maybe even found a better implementation?

Comment: Has anyone been able to implement this more elegantly? What if there is important data attached to the original account, so deleting it isn't an option. Anyone have a working example with the new separated oauth packages?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but the [meteor-accounts-merge](https://github.com/lirbank/meteor-accounts-merge/) package might be worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the example and answer in this posting. It pretty much gives you the code to integrate multiple external and internal accounts. With minor tweaks, you can add the password fields for each account as you desire.

[How to use Meteor.loginWithGoogle with mrt:accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26177463/how-to-use-meteor-loginwithgoogle-with-mrtaccounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown/26179099#26179099)

Code:

```
isProdEnv = function () {
    if (process.env.ROOT_URL == "http://localhost:3000") {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.remove({
    service: 'google'
});

Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.remove({
    service: 'facebook'
});

Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.remove({
    service: 'twitter'
});

Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.remove({
    service: 'github'
});

if (isProdEnv()) {
    Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.insert({
        service: 'github',
        clientId: '00000',
        secret: '00000'
    });
    Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.insert({
        service: 'twitter',
        consumerKey: '00000',
        secret: '00000'
    });
    Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.insert({
        service: 'google',
        appId: '00000',
        secret: '00000'
    });
    Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.insert({
        service: 'facebook',
        appId: '00000',
        secret: '00000'
    });
} else {
    // dev environment
    Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.insert({
        service: 'github',
        clientId: '11111',
        secret: '11111'
    });
    Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.insert({
        service: 'twitter',
        consumerKey: '11111',
        secret: '11111'
    });
    Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.insert({
        service: 'google',
        clientId: '11111',
        secret: '11111'
    });
    Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.insert({
        service: 'facebook',
        appId: '11111',
        secret: '11111'
    });
}

Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {
    if (user.services) {
        if (options.profile) {
            user.profile = options.profile
        }
        var service = _.keys(user.services)[0];
        var email = user.services[service].email;
        if (!email) {
            if (user.emails) {
                email = user.emails.address;
            }
        }
        if (!email) {
            email = options.email;
        }
        if (!email) {
            // if email is not set, there is no way to link it with other accounts
            return user;
        }

        // see if any existing user has this email address, otherwise create new
        var existingUser = Meteor.users.findOne({'emails.address': email});
        if (!existingUser) {
            // check for email also in other services
            var existingGitHubUser = Meteor.users.findOne({'services.github.email': email});
            var existingGoogleUser = Meteor.users.findOne({'services.google.email': email});
            var existingTwitterUser = Meteor.users.findOne({'services.twitter.email': email});
            var existingFacebookUser = Meteor.users.findOne({'services.facebook.email': email});
            var doesntExist = !existingGitHubUser && !existingGoogleUser && !existingTwitterUser && !existingFacebookUser;
            if (doesntExist) {
                // return the user as it came, because there he doesn't exist in the DB yet
                return user;
            } else {
                existingUser = existingGitHubUser || existingGoogleUser || existingTwitterUser || existingFacebookUser;
                if (existingUser) {
                    if (user.emails) {
                        // user is signing in by email, we need to set it to the existing user
                        existingUser.emails = user.emails;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // precaution, these will exist from accounts-password if used
        if (!existingUser.services) {
            existingUser.services = { resume: { loginTokens: [] }};
        }

        // copy accross new service info
        existingUser.services[service] = user.services[service];
        existingUser.services.resume.loginTokens.push(
            user.services.resume.loginTokens[0]
        );

        // even worse hackery
        Meteor.users.remove({_id: existingUser._id}); // remove existing record
        return existingUser;                  // record is re-inserted
    }
});
```