# How does one unify account logins in meteor?

Tags: meteor

Using the accounts packages, i.e.- accounts-ui, accounts-password, accounts-facebook, is it possible to force a single login for one user.

Meaning: if a user creates a login with accounts-password and then creates another login with accounts-facebook is it possible to reconcile those two accounts into one?

I have tried to set the user.services.facebook object of the accounts-password, from server.js, in the MongoDB to the value from the accounts-facebook user... but it does not seem to stick.

I'm doing something like this to attempt to unify the  accounts:

```
unifyFBAccount: function(options){
  var user = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId);
  if(user.services.facebook == null){
    Meteor.users.update(
      {_id: this.userId},
      {$set: {'services.facebook': options.facebook}});
  }
}
```

The options parameter is the user.services object.

Comment: The answer I gave on this question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18576532/194957

Answer (score 1):

[`splendido:accounts-meld`](https://atmospherejs.com/splendido/accounts-meld) should do the trick.