# Meteor user create costumizion

Tags: mongodb, meteor

So right now i got alot of ways to login to my app via facebook/google/github  and more.
but the thing is that for each services i got almost the same data about me, especially the email address and right now for each services meteor creates new account and i was wondering how can i check to see if some user in my DB is already using a certain email (which is unique of course) and instead of creating a new user just extend the services object and if there is no such user yet then create it.(or similar)
(example of extending ):
(user clicks login via facebook):

```
{ "createdAt" : ISODate("2013-11-03T17:13:14.232Z"),
"_id" : "xxx", "services" : { "facebook" : { "accessToken" :xxx", "expiresAt" : xxx, "id" : "1841894180", "email" : "xxx", "name" : "Boaz Hoch", "first_name" : "Boaz"
```

and so on
then after logging out and login with google the user object will look like this:

```
{ "createdAt" : ISODate("2013-11-03T17:13:14.232Z"),
"_id" : "xxx", "services" : { "facebook" : { "accessToken" :xxx", "expiresAt" : xxx, "id" : "1841894180", "email" : "xxx", "name" : "Boaz Hoch", "first_name" : "Boaz" and more of facebook...} //end of facebook service, google:{ { "accessToken" :xxx", "expiresAt" : xxx, "id" : "1841894180", "email" : "xxx", "name" : "Boaz Hoch", "first_name" : "Boaz" and more
```

any best practice for this?

Answer (score 1):

i think i have found what i was looking for, here:[Using Meteor Accounts package to link multiple services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358007/using-meteor-accounts-package-to-link-multiple-services)

going to test it now see if its working.

after if tested it, seems to be working smooth!