# How can I get the credential secret in Meteor, when I do Facebook.requestCredential on the client?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, meteor, facebook-oauth

I'm trying to implement a login/link account system like the one in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358007/using-meteor-accounts-package-to-link-multiple-services?answertab=votes#tab-top).
(scroll down to where it says "Methods for explicit associations")

You used to be able to get the user's login data with something like this:
`data = Package.facebook.Facebook.retrieveCredential(token).serviceData`

Now it looks like this `retrieveCredential(token, secret)`.
Here's the [commit](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2118) where that happened.

I for the life of me can't figure out how to get the credential secret on the server after I  call:

```
Package.facebook.Facebook.requestCredential(
    requestPermissions: Accounts.ui._options.requestPermissions["facebook"]
, (token) ->
    Meteor.call "userAddOauthCredentials", token, Meteor.userId(), service, (err, resp) ->
        if err?
            Meteor.userError.throwError(err.reason)
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out you can do it like this at the moment (on the client):

```
service = "facebook"
Package.facebook.Facebook.requestCredential(
    requestPermissions: Accounts.ui._options.requestPermissions["facebook"]
, (token) ->
    secret = Package.oauth.OAuth._retrieveCredentialSecret(token)
    Meteor.call "userAddOauthCredentials", token, secret, service, (err, resp) ->
        if err?
            Meteor.userError.throwError(err.reason)
)
```

Then on the server you'll need the secret to access the service data for the user.

```
userAddOAuthCredentials: (token, secret, service) ->
    services = Meteor.user().services
    serviceSearch = {}
    data = {}
    switch service
        when "facebook"
            if not services.facebook?
                data = Package.facebook.Facebook.retrieveCredential(token, secret)?.serviceData
                services.facebook = data
                serviceSearch = {"services.facebook.id": services.facebook.id}
            else
                throw new Meteor.Error(500, "You already have a linked Facebook account with email #{services.facebook.email}...")
    oldUser = Meteor.users.findOne(serviceSearch)
    if oldUser?
        throw new Meteor.Error(500, "Your #{service} account has already been assigned to another user.")

    Meteor.users.update(@userId, {$set: {services: services}})
    if data.email?
        if not _.contains(Meteor.user().emails, data.email)
            Meteor.users.update(@userId, {$push: {"emails": {address: data.email, verified: true}}})
```

Those functions will get you the user's service data so you can link multiple accounts, or do whatever you want with them.