# Problems connecting Facebook via OAuth

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, meteor, oauth

I've installed the Meteor [Facebook](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/facebook) package and the [OAuth](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/oauth) package to allow users to connect their Facebook accounts.

I found some code in [a Stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24428130/how-can-i-get-the-credential-secret-in-meteor-when-i-do-facebook-requestcredent). I've implemented a client-side handler to start the authorization flow

```
'click #facebook-connect': function(e) {
  var service;

  service = "facebook";

  Facebook.requestCredential({
    requestPermissions: ["email"]}, function(token) {
    var secret;
    secret = OAuth._retrieveCredentialSecret(token);
    return Meteor.call("userAddOAuthCredentials", token, service, secret, function(err, resp) {
      if (err != null) {
        return Meteor.userError.throwError(err.reason);
      }
    });
  });
},
```

and a server-side method to add the Facebook token to the database which is called by the client-side button click.

```
Meteor.methods({
'userAddOAuthCredentials':  function(token, service, secret) {
  var data, oldUser, ref, serviceSearch, services;
  services = Meteor.user().services;
  serviceSearch = {};
  data = {};
  switch (service) {
    case "facebook":
      if (services.facebook == null) {
        data = (ref = Facebook.retrieveCredential(token, secret)) != null ? ref.serviceData : void 0;
        services.facebook = data;
        serviceSearch = {
          "services.facebook.id": services.facebook.id
        };
      } else {
        throw new Meteor.Error(500, "You already have a linked Facebook account with email " + services.facebook.email + "...");
      }
  }
  oldUser = Meteor.users.findOne(serviceSearch);
  if (oldUser != null) {
    throw new Meteor.Error(500, "Your " + service + " account has already been assigned to another user.");
  }
  Meteor.users.update(this.userId, {
    $set: {
      services: services
    }
  });
  if (data.email != null) {
    if (!_.contains(Meteor.user().emails, data.email)) {
      return Meteor.users.update(this.userId, {
        $push: {
          "emails": {
            address: data.email,
            verified: true
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
});
```

I get this stack trace when it runs:

```
I20150627-13:23:00.794(-4)? Exception while invoking method 'userAddOAuthCredentials' TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
I20150627-13:23:00.794(-4)?   at [object Object].Meteor.methods.userAddOAuthCredentials (app/server/methods/facebook.js:13:52)
I20150627-13:23:00.794(-4)?   at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (/Users/raddevon/Documents/projects/resque/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/ddp.js:2445:12)
I20150627-13:23:00.794(-4)?   at _.extend.protocol_handlers.method.exception (/Users/raddevon/Documents/projects/resque/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/ddp.js:1476:20)
I20150627-13:23:00.795(-4)?   at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/Users/raddevon/Documents/projects/resque/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/meteor.js:989:17)
I20150627-13:23:00.795(-4)?   at /Users/raddevon/Documents/projects/resque/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/ddp.js:1475:41
I20150627-13:23:00.795(-4)?   at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/Users/raddevon/Documents/projects/resque/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/meteor.js:989:17)
I20150627-13:23:00.795(-4)?   at [object Object]._.extend.protocol_handlers.method (/Users/raddevon/Documents/projects/resque/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/ddp.js:1474:51)
I20150627-13:23:00.795(-4)?   at _.extend.processMessage.processNext (/Users/raddevon/Documents/projects/resque/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/ddp.js:1374:43)
```

The client-side code never gets the secret into the server-side method. Why is this happening, and how can I get a proper client secret to pass to my server method?

Comment: What line do you get the error on for the the undefined object? And why don't you just use accounts-facebook package? Or at least see the code for that package

Comment: @EliezerSteinbock I'll check for the line number in a few minutes. Not in front of it at the moment. I have looked at accounts-facebook, but I haven't been able to learn anything from it. I'm not using it because I don't need users to log in to the app using Facebook. I just want to authorize them so we can post on their behalf.